# Check if a character is a vowel or consonant?

Tags: c#, character

Is there a code to check if a character is a vowel or consonant? Some thing like char = IsVowel? Or need to hard code?

```
case ‘a’:
case ‘e’:
case ‘i’:
case ‘o’:
case ‘u’:
case ‘A’:
case ‘E’:
case ‘I’:
case ‘O’:
case ‘U’:
```

Comment: think a logic and  make it an extension method. `:)`

Comment: Check this [C# program to check whether a input character is vowel or not](http://www.msccomputerscience.com/2014/04/c-program-to-check-whether-input_23.html)

Answer (score 44, accepted):

You could do this:

```
char c = ...
bool isVowel = "aeiouAEIOU".IndexOf(c) >= 0;
```

or this:

```
char c = ...
bool isVowel = "aeiou".IndexOf(c.ToString(), StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase) >= 0;
```

Once you add international support for things like `éèe̋ȅëêĕe̊æøи` etc. this string will get long, but the basic solution is the same.

Comment: Or for .NET 3.5 or later, simply `"aeiouAEIOU".Contains(c)`.

Comment: @JukkaK.Korpela Because it's not always. In "Why", it's considered a vowel while in "Yawn", it's a consonant.

Comment: Doesn't InvariantCulture take care of éèe̋ȅëêĕe̊æøи? So é = e and you don't have to append them to you string.

Comment: @gijswijs No: `"é".Equals("e", StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase)` → `False`.

Answer (score 10):

Here's a function that works:

```
public static class CharacterExtentions
{
    public static bool IsVowel(this char c)
    {
        long x = (long)(char.ToUpper(c)) - 64;
        if (x*x*x*x*x - 51*x*x*x*x + 914*x*x*x - 6894*x*x + 20205*x - 14175 == 0) return true;
        else return false;
    }
}
```

Use it like:

```
char c = 'a';
if (c.IsVowel()) { // it's a Vowel!!! }
```

(Yes, it ***really works***, but obviously, this is a *joke* answer.  Don't downvote me.  or whatever.)

Comment: Anonymous Downvoter - you obviously didn't follow my instructions.   Or maybe you did - I'm not sure.   ;)

Comment: Not my downvote, but I'm guessing the reason was that you didn't explain *how* this works. Also it happens to return true for a [dot-less lowercase i](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dotted_and_dotless_I) (`ı`) but for no other non-Latin vowel.

Comment: Interesting that the "dotless lowercase i" returns 'true' - it must be a quirk of `char.ToUpper`.  As for not explaining how it works, like most jokes (as I did clearly identify this as a joke), if I have to explain it then it takes all the fun out of it.  I figured there would be two groups of people - those who immediately understood how it works, and would appreciate the "ingenuity" (however much of it there was), and those that don't get it at first, but might have a fun time figuring it out.  Of course, if anyone can't figure it out and asks, *then* I'd be happy to explain.

Comment: This it the best solution !

Comment: this is absolutely brilliant :D

Comment: Ok, it's awesome! Can you explain how it works? Also, you could just return the 'if' condition and reduce that extra line of code. :)

Comment: Polynomials!! First subtract the char code with 64 so that 'A' = 1 then you create a polynomial equation: (x - 1) * (x - 5) * (x - 9) * (x - 15) * (x - 21) = 0.

Answer (score 4):

No. You need to define first what you regard as a vowel and as a consonant. For example, in English, “y” could be a consonant (as in “yes”) or a vowel (as in “by”). Letters like “é” and “ü” are probably vowels in all languages in which they are used, but it seems that you did not consider them at all. Primarily, you should define *why* you wish to classify letters as consonants and vowels.

Answer (score 4):

```
Console.WriteLine("Please input a word or phrase:");
string userInput = Console.ReadLine().ToLower();

for (int i = 0; i < userInput.Length; i++)
        {
            //c stores the index of userinput and converts it to string so it is readable and the program wont bomb out.[i]means position of the character.
            string c = userInput[i].ToString();
            if ("aeiou".Contains(c))
            {
                vowelcount++;
            }
        }
        Console.WriteLine(vowelcount);
```

Answer (score 2):

The other methods given work. Here I am concerned with performance. For the two approaches I tested - using LINQ's Any method and using bit arithmetic, the use of bit arithmetic was more than ten times faster. Results:

> Time for LINQ      = 117 msec
>
> Time for Bit masks = 8 msec

```
public static bool IsVowelLinq(char c)
{
    char[] vowels = new[] { 'a', 'e', 'i', 'o', 'u', 'A', 'E', 'I', 'O', 'U' };
    return vowels.Any(ch => ch == c);
}

private static int VowelMask = (1 << 1) | (1 << 5) | (1 << 9) | (1 << 15) | (1 << 21);

public static bool IsVowelBitArithmetic(char c)
{
    // The OR with 0x20 lowercases the letters
    // The test c > 64 rules out punctuation, digits, and control characters.
    // An additional test would be required to eliminate characters above ASCII 127.
    return (c > 64) && ((VowelMask &  (1 << ((c | 0x20) % 32))) != 0);
}
```

See https://dotnetfiddle.net/WbPHU4 for the code in a test with timings.

The key idea with the bit mask is that the second bit is set for 'a', the sixth bit is set for 'e', etc. Then you take the letter, shift left by its ASCII value as an integer, and see if that bit in the mask is set. One bit is set in the mask for each vowel, and the OR operation performs the lowercasing of the letter first.

Comment: Calling "new" inside the LINQ version is the bulk of why it's slow.

Comment: Also, an array is too slow for searching. Making "vowels" a HashSet and moving it to a static member makes it 10 times faster and only a little slower than bitmasks.

Answer (score 1):

You can use "IsVowel" as you wanted. However the only thing is there is likely no default C# library or function that already does this out of the box, well if this is what you wanted. You will need to write a util method for this.

```
bool a = isVowel('A');//example method call 

public bool isVowel(char charValue){
    char[] vowelList = {'a', 'e', 'i', 'o', 'u'};

    char casedChar = char.ToLower(charValue);//handle simple and capital vowels

    foreach(char vowel in vowelList){
        if(vowel == casedChar){
            return true;
        }
    }

    return false;
}
```

Comment: This isn't C#, obviously, which is what the OP tagged his question as.

Comment: Ah your right missed that and it was originally written in Java, it is in C# now then

Answer (score 1):

This works just fine.

```
public static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        int vowelsInString = 0;
        int consonants = 0;
        int lengthOfString;
        char[] vowels = new char[5] { 'a', 'e', 'i', 'o', 'u' };

        string ourString;
        Console.WriteLine("Enter a sentence or a word");
        ourString = Console.ReadLine();
        ourString = ourString.ToLower();

        foreach (char character in ourString)
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < vowels.Length; i++)
            {
                if (vowels[i] == character) 
                {
                    vowelsInString++;
                }
            }
        }
        lengthOfString = ourString.Count(c => !char.IsWhiteSpace(c)); //gets the length of the string without any whitespaces
        consonants = lengthOfString - vowelsInString; //Well, you get the idea.
        Console.WriteLine();
        Console.WriteLine("Vowels in our string: " + vowelsInString);
        Console.WriteLine("Consonants in our string " + consonants);
        Console.ReadKey();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, none of the existing answers handles accented letters. The following code does (as it is, only for Latin alphabets but it's very straightforward to modify or include others as well):

```
public static string IsFirstVowel(this string s) {
  char[] Vowels = new[] { 'a', 'e', 'i', 'o', 'u' };
  string Normalized = s.First().ToString().ToLowerInvariant().Normalize(NormalizationForm.FormD);
  foreach (char c in Normalized) {
    if (CharUnicodeInfo.GetUnicodeCategory(c) != UnicodeCategory.NonSpacingMark) {
      Normalized = c.ToString().Normalize(NormalizationForm.FormC);
      return Vowels.Contains(Normalized.First());
    }
  }
  return false;
}
```

Comment: This doesn't take into account that the letter 'Y' is considered a vowel in some languages but you pointed me in the right direction!

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like this in.

```
  private bool IsCharacterAVowel(char c)
  {
     string vowels = "aeiou";
     return vowels.IndexOf(c.ToString(),StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase) >= 0;      
  }
```

Comment: This is case sensitive

Comment: @SriramSakthivel He wanted an idea not working code. written pseudocode just to give an idea of what he should do.

Answer (score 0):

Why not create an array of the vowels/consonants and check if the value is in the array?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following extension method:

```
using System;
using System.Linq;

public static class CharExtentions
{
    public static bool IsVowel(this char character)
    {
        return new[] {'a', 'e', 'i', 'o', 'u'}.Contains(char.ToLower(character));
    }
}
```

Use it like:

```
'c'.IsVowel(); // Returns false
'a'.IsVowel(); // Returns true
```

Answer (score 0):

```
return "aeiou".Any( c => c.Equals( Char.ToLowerInvariant( myChar ) ) );
```

Comment: More clear code will be if you once convert value to lower value and use 'Contains'

Answer (score 0):

Try this out:

```
char[] inputChars = Console.ReadLine().ToCharArray();
int vowels = 0;
int consonants = 0;
foreach (char c in inputChars)
{
   if ("aeiou".Contains(c) || "AEIOU".Contains(c))
   {
       vowels++;
   }
   else
   {
       consonants++;
   }
}
Console.WriteLine("Vowel count: {0} - Consonant count: {1}", vowels, consonants);
Console.ReadKey();
```

Answer (score 0):

Look at this code to check for both Vowel and Consonant , C#

```
private static void Vowel(string value)
{
    int vowel = 0;
    foreach (var x in value.ToLower())
    {
        if (x.Equals('a') || x.Equals('e') || x.Equals('i') || x.Equals('o') || x.Equals('u'))
        {
            vowel += 1;
        }
    } 
    Console.WriteLine( vowel + " number of vowels");
}

private static void Consonant(string value)
{
    int cont = 0;
    foreach (var x in value.ToLower())
    {
        if (x > 'a' && x <= 'd' || x > 'e' && x < 'i' || x > 'j' && x < 'o' || x >= 'p' && x < 'u' || x > 'v' && x < 'z')
        {
            cont += 1;
        }
    }
    Console.WriteLine(cont + " number of consonant");
}
```