# C# find vowels from char, display

Tags: c#

I have the following code:

```
Console.Writeline("[Server] Message of client received");
for (int i = 0; i < totalBytes; i++)
{
    aChar = Convert.ToChar(incomingDataBuffer[i]);
    Console.Write(aChar);
}
```

where `int totalBytes = aSocket.Receive(incomingDataBuffer);`

In addition to printing the message like above, I need to iterate through the message and print it again, but remove consonants. So "Hello there" would return "eoee".

If someone could give a working example that would be great. I don't know C# but I'm learning Java now.

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17764680/check-if-a-character-is-a-vowel-or-consonant

Comment: This is definitely a homework question

Comment: Hint: you can filter elements out of a sequence by using the `Where` sequence operator.

Comment: I think the key point of the question is: *"in addition to printing the message like above"*. I'm pretty positive that's bad wording from the OP, but if you stick to that sentence, most "good" solutions become invalid :-)

Comment: Thanks for all the I put, I ended up adding an if statement, checking each vowel and then assigning the char to an empty string. Although, I wasn't able to get it to print out the original message as well, which was the intent.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add the vowels to a string and print them afterwards. Something like:

```
Console.Writeline("[Server] Message of client received");
string vowels = string.Empty; // start with an empty string
for (int i = 0; i < totalBytes; i++)
{
   aChar = Convert.ToChar(incomingDataBuffer[i]);
   Console.Write(aChar);
   // if it's a vowel add it to the "vowels" string
   if("aeiouAEIOU".Contains(aChar)) vowels += aChar;
}
Console.Write(vowels); // print it out
```

PS: note that "vowels" might be different depending on your language... you need to define what is a vowel for you (in many cases, `y` would be a vowel in English, for example, or accented letters, like `é` or `ü`). I've simplified it to the `a-e-i-o-u` case, but it might be incorrect.

Comment: Thanks! I ended up doing something very similar to this

Answer (score 1):

Here's a quick example that shows how to iterate over a string and check for vowels.

```
// The input.
// Your question is a little unclear and I couldn't understand how you get this string...
var message = "[Server] Message of         client received";

// Iterate over each character
for (int i = 0; i < message.Length; i++)
{
    // Check if character is a vowel and output if it is
    if ("aeiouAEIOU".IndexOf(message[i]) >= 0)
        Console.Write(message[i]);
}
```

Input:

> [Server] Message of         client received

Output:

> eeeaeoieeeie

Comment: Thanks! I ended up doing something very similar to this.