# How to check if the last letter of a string is vowel

Tags: c#, jquery

Can someone help me with my code. I want to check the last letter of a word if it is vowel or not. If it is a vowel, i want to add "ce" after it. Say, the input from a user is "apple" and because this ends with a vowel, the output will be "applece". If it is consonant, the output will be the user's input only without the "ce". I actually created a code, but I stumbled upon this error [object HTMLInputElement]. Can someone fix my code and can finally achieve an output

```
@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Taxi";
}
<html>
<body>
    <br />
    <br />
    <br />
    <br />
    <br />
    Enter a word:
    <input id="input1">
    <br />
    <br />
    <input type="submit" value="SUBMIT" id="submit"><br /><br />

    <p id="dsplyresult1"></p>



</body>
</html>
<script src="~/Scripts/JQUERY/jquery-3.6.3.min.js"></script>
<script src="~/Scripts/MyScript/Tax.js"></script>
```

```
$().ready(function () {
    $("#submit").click(function () {


        var x;
        var x = $("#input1").val();


        if (x.endsWith('a') || x.endsWith('e') || x.endsWith('i') ||
            x.endsWith('o') || x.endsWith('u') || x.endsWith('A') ||
            x.endsWith('E') || x.endsWith('I') || x.endsWith('O') || x.endsWith('U')) {
            do {
                $("#dsplyresult1").text(input1 + "pa");
            }

            while (true);
        }
        else
            $("#dsplyresult1").text(input1);

    });

});
```

Comment: See this [SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17764680/check-if-a-character-is-a-vowel-or-consonant) question

Comment: What does this have to do with C#?

Comment: I'm not sure what the `do/while` loop is trying to achieve, but it should not be there. Here is an example: https://jsfiddle.net/76484/5rjaxukc/

Comment: you're adding `"pa"`, not `"ce"`...

Comment: yeah it's pa. But I want to convert my code using do while loop

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Check if a character is a vowel or consonant?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17764680/check-if-a-character-is-a-vowel-or-consonant)

Comment: I wonder why the tags include `c#` when the code snippets are HTML and Javascript.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. You don't need a `do/while(true)` endless loop.
2. You can just use the value of `x` instead of `input`
3. You said you want to add "ce", but in your code you're adding "pa"

To fix this, you can just do:

```
if (x.endsWith('a') || x.endsWith('e') || 
    x.endsWith('i') || x.endsWith('o') || 
    x.endsWith('u') || x.endsWith('A') ||
    x.endsWith('E') || x.endsWith('I') || 
    x.endsWith('O') || x.endsWith('U'))
{
    $("#dsplyresult1").text(x + 'ce');
}
else
{
    $("#dsplyresult1").text(x);
}
```

Comment: thankss but is there a way to convert it into a for loop, while and do while loop

Comment: I suppose you could iterate over all the vowels in a loop, set a flag variable, and then determine the output. But why would you want to?